# Is there any way for assigning external metadata to files?

Tags: pdf, metadata, indexing

I need a way of assigning tags and numbers (like rating, importance, etc) to my files and also be able do queries and file operations based on these metadata. Just like a photo management software (e.g. F-spot) but for documents (PDF, DJVU, EPUB, etc).

This can be a file manager with extra abilities or a file indexing system. The only thing I've found so far is [recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/) however it doesn't allow me to assign tags to files.

By the way, I've been using XFCE for quite a while so if Gnome has such a software built-in, I may not know about it.

Comment: With "external" you mean that the metadata should *not* be saved in the files, correct?

Comment: Well, some file formats may not support in-file metadata. Also for fast searches, the metadata must be stored in a database.

Comment: Are you OK with an app taking over the management of your library and imposing its own sorting structure? If so then a full document management suite like [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) might be your best choice. You can also go down the manual path and use [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to edit the embedded metadata in your files. If you want you can index this metadata with Recoll: https://bitbucket.org/medoc/recoll/wiki/HandleCustomField http://www.freelists.org/post/recoll-user/indexing-and-searching-customized-metadata-fields-in-pdf

Answer (score 0):

I do love [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/). Just like it's said on the site About page "Calibre is a free and open source e-book library management application developed by users of e-books for users of e-books".